# CSS linear gradient transparency misbehaving only in Safari

Tags: css

Something really strange is happening in Safari. I'm doing a simple gradient overlay to do a text fade effect. It works fine in Firefox and Chrome, but not Safari, which I find strange since Safari and Chrome are both Webkit based.

## Safari

[image]

## Chrome and Firefox

[image]

## CSS Code

```
.text-fade {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, white, transparent);
  bottom: 0;
  height: 25%;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Instead of:

```
background: linear-gradient(to top, white, transparent);
```

Try setting your transparent to an rgba color value. For example:

```
background: linear-gradient(to top, white, rgba(255,255,255,0));
```

In other words, the rgb value of both colors should match. For example:

```
background: linear-gradient(to top, red, rgba(255,0,0,0));
```

As defined by the w3c spec, transparent is *black* transparent (rgba(0,0,0,0)). That means that when you are in the middle of the transition, some black should appear.

The color seen in Safari is the correct one, as per the specs.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I already tried that, didn't fix it though.

Comment: Oh! Shoot, I see what I did wrong. You're right, it does work. Safari doesn't like the `transparent` keyword in gradients, apparently. Thanks!

Comment: Added a little explanation of the reason behind this.

Comment: The only explanation that I have found so far that gives the root cause! Thanks!

Comment: _In other words, the rgb value of both colors should match._ -Thanks. This helped me a lot.