# CSS3 Gradient with transparency not displaying correctly in Safari

Tags: css, safari

This is a puzzle. The following gradient doesn't display correctly in Safari (works in Firefox and Chrome):

```
background: linear-gradient(transparent 124px, #de6230);
```

I have also tried:

```
background: linear-gradient(rgba(255,0,0,0) 124px, #de6230);
```

Test it on Safari and you will see the issue: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4wd1qp5t/4/).

How do I fix this?

Comment: I can see the issue, very interesting. May be a browser bug?

Comment: What does actually happens?

Comment: Second one should work. @LGSon - [Check this out](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#transparent), it renders as `rgba(0,0,0,0)` which is probably adding some black tinge shade to the gradient/

Comment: @Mr.Alien Agree it should, OP said not, hence my comment ... don't have Safari though so can't do much more

Comment: @LGSon The first part of that comment was for OP :) and same here, no Safari, but the place where I work, we have built a cross-browser testing platform online so I tested there :)

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30673204/css-linear-gradient-transparency-misbehaving-only-in-safari

Comment: Another funny possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38391457/linear-gradient-to-transparent-bug-in-latest-safari

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0) 124px, #de6230);

Edit: sorry OP, that still doesn't look the same as your gradient although it is the correct colors, the gray middle just turned to a white middle. The solution I found was:

```
background: linear-gradient(rgba(222,98,48,0) 124px, #de6230);
```

222,98,48 is the rgb value of #de6230 so this should work. It's transitioning from your color at 0% alpha to your color at 100% alpha.

Comment: OP wrote they tried (255, 0, 0, 0) not (255, 255, 255, 0)

Comment: Are you kidding with me ... both have alpha 0, which mean fully transparent

Comment: But the browser is still showing part of it as it transitions away from transparent. That's why it's showing the gray color, because firefox (edit: whoops I meant safari) interprets transparent as black with alpha = 0%.

Comment: You are right though, that just replaces the gray problem with a white problem. The solution I found was to use     background: linear-gradient(rgba(222,98,48,0) 124px, #de6230);

Comment: Outstanding; this is the one! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(255,0,0,0) 124px, #de6230);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(255,0,0,0) 124px, #de6230);
background: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(255,0,0,0) 124px, #de6230);
background: linear-gradient(rgba(255,0,0,0) 124px, #de6230);
```

or replace *background* with *background-image*

```
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(255,0,0,0) 124px, #de6230);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(255,0,0,0) 124px, #de6230);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(255,0,0,0) 124px, #de6230);
background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255,0,0,0) 124px, #de6230);
```

[image: https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css3_gradients.asp]

Comment: Lets see if `background-image:` will make a difference