# CSS3 Gradient difference | Chrome vs Safari

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients, css-gradients

I'm using a CSS3 gradient like so:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent, #03143f);
```

The issue I'm having is that safari is adding a black tinge to the gradient where as Chrome is fading nicely.

Has anyone experienced this issue before?

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fwkgM/1126/)

Safari

[image]

Chrome

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate [linear-gradient-to-transparent-bug-in-latest-safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38391457/linear-gradient-to-transparent-bug-in-latest-safari)

Comment: Safaru bug: https://github.com/Compass/compass/issues/2010

Comment: Another possible duplicate [css3-gradient-with-transparency-not-displaying-correctly-in-safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42352142/css3-gradient-with-transparency-not-displaying-correctly-in-safari)

Comment: Let me know if any dupe link solves it for you and I close it as such

Comment: None of these dupes solve it sadly.

Comment: The the second does solve it, as you'll need to set the calculated value instead of transparent

Comment: I've tried all versions of calc values, transparent etc - still no results. ohh maan haha!