# Transparent gradient issue over colour background in Safari

Tags: css, gradient

I'm aware of multiple [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11829410/css3-gradient-rendering-issues-from-transparent-to-white) [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30673204/css-linear-gradient-transparency-misbehaving-only-in-safari) regarding an issue with using `transparent` as a colour value in Safari and needing to use `rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)` as an alternative, but it's not working for me. I'm using the gradient as a "Show More" fade, which has a dark gray background, and the gradient still doesn't look smooth in Safari:

[image]

And in Chrome:

[image]

Demo: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RLEOyX)

The `:after` gradient is `background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, #2b2b2b 100%)` and the section background colour is `#2b2b2b`. What do I need to use for the gradient instead?

Answer (score 1):

Try fading from black (instead of white) to #2b2b2b:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, #2b2b2b 100%)
```